# global gitignore being, um, ignored

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I am running xampp on my windows machine. I have a load of git repos running locally on c:/xampp/htdocs and wish to add a global ignore to ignore the database config file which is in the applications/config folder of all these repos.

I've created .gitignore_global in the htdocs folder and run `git config --global core.excludesfile .gitignore_global` whilst in the htdocs folder and then navigated to one of my repos and run `git rm --cached application/config/database.php` then added, committed and pushed. The file is removed on github, fine, but when I amend database.php and run `git status` it shows the file there, waiting to be added.... I've researched this and tried a load of things but can't see what I'm doing wrong... any ideas?

Comment: what's in your `.getignore_global`?

Comment: literally just `database.php`. Should it include the path?

Comment: check that you don't have a local override of `core.excludesfile` with `git config --get core.excludesfile`

Comment: This is what I get: `$ git config --get core.excludesfile
.gitignore_global`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the absolute path of `.gitignore_global` in `git config --global core.excludesfile`, as it is shared by all repositories on your machine git must know where it is!

Comment: Aha! So something like `C:\xampp\htdocs\.gitignore_global` or forward slashes?

Comment: I've done the above and its still wanting to commit the database file if I change it. I've tried the `git rm --cached application/config/database.php` but it still doesn't work... any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you create another file `database.php`, does it show in `git status`?

Comment: I was being stupid because it's too late - I put the absolute url on the database.php inside the file - no wonder it didn't work! brainfreeze... haha! Sorry, its working fine now - thanks so much for all youy help :)